# instantiation of a template constructor of template class

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, member

What's wrong with the following code? [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045879/explicit-instantiation-of-templated-constructor-for-template-class) doesn't help me.

exts.h:

```
template <typename T> class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    MyClass(const MyClass& tocopy);
    template <typename U> MyClass(const MyClass<U>& tocopy);
    // ...
};
```

exts.cpp:

```
#include "exts.h"
template <typename T> MyClass<T>::MyClass() {}
template <typename T> MyClass<T>::MyClass(const MyClass& tocopy)
{// ... }

template <typename T> template <typename U> MyClass<T>::MyClass(const MyClass<U>& tocopy)
{// ... }

template class MyClass<int>;    //instantiation of the class
template class MyClass<double>; //instantiation of the class
template MyClass<double>::MyClass(const MyClass<int>); //instantiation of specifized class member? ERROR here!!
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "exts.h"
//...
MyClass<double> a; //...
MyClass<int> b(a);
```

The error I get under VS2012++ at the line noted is:

> error C3190: 'MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass)' with the
>   provided template arguments is not the explicit instantiation of any
>   member function of 'MyClass'

And under g++ is:

> exts.cpp:18:10: error: template-id ‘MyClass<>’ for
>   ‘MyClass::MyClass(MyClass)’ does not match any template
>   declaration  template MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass);

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
template MyClass<double>::MyClass(const MyClass<int>); //instantiation of specifized class member? ERROR here!!
```

with

```
template MyClass<double>::MyClass(const MyClass<int>&); //instantiation of specifized class member? ERROR here!!
```